# Google Oauth2, should I use token provided by Google or generate my own token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

So I'm implementing Login with Google feature using Spring Java. I followed the Spring documentation setup and it works just fine. My resource server setup looks like this.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          issuer-uri: https://accounts.google.com
          jwk-set-uri: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs
```

However the token provided by Google does not contain information that I need in order to perform authorization such as `USER_ROLES`, `USER_AUTHORITY` and etc. So I'm considering doing this

1. Login with Google OAuth2 flow, if authenticated go to the next step,
2. Use the token from Google to get user-info from `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json`.
3. Create a User record in the database, if doesnt exist before, which will contain user information including `ROLES` and etc.
4. Generate a new sets of token which has claims that I need for authorization part and also refresh token machanism.
5. Config resource server to use `jwk-set-uri` from my authorization server instead.

I'm also planning to support Facebook login and Github login as well using the same approach as above so is it safe to do this or any better ways recommend.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the audience claim (`aud`) in the access token (or associated to it in case of introspection). If your resource server is not part of this audience, it should not accept it.

If you want to associate your own claims to identities and take control on the token format, audience, etc., your intention is the right one: use your own authorization server and configure others as identity sources. This new authorization server will be the only reference for your clients and resource servers.

Keycloak is a quite popular solution to do that. But if you are using only "external" identity sources (don't need registration and login for users not having or not wanting to share an external account), you could also consider Spring Authorization Server.